# Remove ?la=en parameter in assets - how?

Tags: media-library, multilingual

Our site has only one language and therefore the '?la=en' parameter attached to several static assets (mainly images) is totally redundant.

Is it possible to remove this from the entire site?

Comment: what sitecore version are you using?

Comment: The site is done in Sitecore version 8.0

Comment: How is your linkmanager configured? By default the `languageEmbedding` is set to `asNeeded` but what happens if you set it to `never`? Does this resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Since your site only has one language you can configure the LinkManager to always generate URLs without any language parameters

You can configure this using a patch file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <linkManager>
            <providers>
                <add name="sitecore">
                    <patch:attribute name="languageEmbedding">never</patch:attribute>
                </add>
            </providers>
        </linkManager>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

And if at a later date you do want to enable languageEmbedding for a specific site you can have a look at this blogpost:
https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/02/03/site-specific-link-provider-for-multi-site-implementation-in-sitecore/

Comment: I had updated the setting through direct edit of the web.config file. I understand that this may not be future proof and will apply a patch file for all the changes we have done. However, this does not solve the problem.

Comment: You can try checking if the `Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage` setting is set to `true`. It should be by default.

Comment: No success yet in global stripping. However, by avoiding the use of .ashx and directly using .png, .jpg etc, I am able to avoid suffixing ?la=en.